# Remove a directory with ISAPI RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, isapi-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite a web address to remove a directory, if it exists. In other words, if someone navigates to `www.domain.com/a/bad/b/c/page.pdf`, the RewriteRule should remove `/bad/` and send them to `www.domain.com/a/b/c/page.pdf`.

The `/bad/` directory will always be in the 2nd position in the URL, as in the example. The paths will always be to PDFs, if that makes a difference.

I've tried things, but no luck. I feel like this should be fairly simple. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

OK, after more digging I found my answer:

```
RewriteRule ^a/bad/(.*)$ /a/$1
```